# IE float hover issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hello guys) seems like I have pretty common issue with :hover'ing over floated list elements in IE, though I didn't find any solution so far. IE11 + WIN7. Here is my HTML...

```
<!doctype html>
...
<ul id="horizontal-menu">
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And I have my CSS this way...

```
#horizontal-menu {
    list-style: none;
}

#horizontal-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

#horizontal-menu li a {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

#horizontal-menu li a:hover, #horizontal-menu li a:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The problem is that in IE the actual :hover area of those list item links has a strange left margin, and it works fine for the rest of the browsers...

Though I don't have enough reputation to post images, [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img843/3843/vc8m.gif) you gonna find a fast link to my explanatory drowings...

Need your good advice fellas :/ tnx

...

Just used this !DOCTYPE...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

didn't solve the issue...

...

Just removed the display:inline-block rule from both li and a elements... didn't work for me

...

Removed also all possible inherited margins and paddings... still the same

The issue still exists

Comment: what version of IE, looks fine in 10

Comment: using IE11 on Windows7

Answer (score 0):

remove the `display:inline-block` rule from both `li` and `a` elements

Comment: didn't get the result, tnx

Comment: Check if your `a` tags don't inherit some margins from somewhere else, or even `li` items havings paddings from previous declared rules.

Comment: Nope... still the [same](http://imageshack.com/a/img809/8969/fgu.gif "IE11 list item float issue") experience...

Comment: can you provide a url to your website? it would be very helpful so solve your issue

Comment: developing locally, didn't host it anywhere by this time... will see what I can do